# Is it unspecified to instantiate template/lambda in unevaluated context?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, language-lawyer, instantiation

I try following code to check if template are instantiated in unevaluated context:

```cpp
#include "foo.h"

template <typename T = int>
constexpr auto f(int)
// from declaration, foo(std::declval<T>()) is allowed.
// Even if definition would produce errors if instantiated
-> decltype(foo(std::declval<T>()), void(), 42)
{
    return 42;
}
static_assert(f(0) == 42);
```

with `foo` as template function: (No errors)

```cpp
template <typename ...Ts>
void foo(Ts... args)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == 42, "!");
    ((args += ""), ...);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5157042e07c2f778)

with `foo` as regular functor: (No errors)

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    template <typename ...Ts>
    void operator ()(Ts... args) const
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(args) == 42, "!");
        ((args += ""), ...);
    }
} foo;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e41c4623dd4fe020)

But `foo` as lambda: (Error)

```cpp
auto foo = [](auto... args)
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(args) == 42, "!"); // Triggers
    ((args += ""), ...);                       // spotted as invalid: int += const char*
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/559909484a8566d8)

Is it normal that `operator()` of lamdba is instantiated?

gcc/clang have same behavior.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The lambda case is actually different than the others! You don't specify a return type for the lambda, so it is deduced. For the deduction to happen the lambda has to be instantiated.

This is not the case for the function object, since there you specified the return type to be `void`. Changing the lambda to return `void` to avoid the deduction makes gcc/clang happy. :)

```
auto foo = [](auto... args) -> void // <---
{
    static_assert(sizeof...(args) == 42, "!");
    ((args += ""), ...);
};
```

And if you change the function object as follows:

```
struct Foo
{
    template <typename ...Ts>
    auto operator ()(Ts... args) const // <---- placeholder as return type
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(args) == 42, "!");
        ((args += ""), ...);
    }
} foo;
```

it does also instantiate `Foo::operator()` to be able to deduce the return type.